# Get substring containing first N words in C# .NET using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to obtain a string containing the first N words from a given string. E.g.

Get first **5 words** from *The quick_brown, fox1 jumps over the lazy dog* 
should return ***The quick_brown, fox1 jumps over***

Notice that word include letters, digits and _ (basically \W+ match) and all the original separators (e.g. ,) are kept.

I managed to do this using classic C# code like this:

```
public static bool IsWordChar(this char c)
{
    return char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_';
}

public static string GetFirstWords(string s, int wordCount, string truncateSuffix = " [...]")
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int currWordCount = 0;
    char prevC = '\0';
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        sb.Append(c);
        if (!c.IsWordChar() && prevC.IsWordChar())
            currWordCount++;

        if (currWordCount >= wordCount)
        {
            if (sb.Length < s.Length)
                sb.Append(truncateSuffix);

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        prevC = c;
    }

    // adding last word, if necessary
    if (prevC.IsWordChar())
        sb.Append(prevC);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It works fast enough for my needs (O(n)), but I am wondering if this can be achieved using regular expressions.

I have tried using `\W+` and take the first N matches, but I loose the actual non-word separators from the original text.

**Question: Is there a C# regex equivalent of the above code?**

Thanks.

Comment: I think you could try `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)^(\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){4}).*", "$1 [...]")`, see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%5e%28%5cW*%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a%5cW%2b%5cw%2b%29%7b4%7d%29.*&i=The+quick_brown%2c+fox1+jumps+over+the+lazy+dog+&r=%241+%5b...%5d). If the string is expected to contain  fewer than 5 words and the result should then contain the whole input, replace `{4}` with `{0,4}`.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly with Match (no need for Replace). Please, post it as an answer, so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Regex will be slower than your method (at least if the string is large so it matters), so don't replace it for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex to extract a siubstring containing the first five words from a longer string is

```
@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){4}"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5CW*%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A%5CW%2B%5Cw%2B%29%7B4%7D&i=The%20quick_brown%2C%20fox1%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog%20)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word symbols
- `\w+` -  1+ word symbols
- `(?:\W+\w+){4}` - 4 sequences (replace with `{0,4}` if the number of words may be fewer than 5 in the input string and the expected output is the whole string then) of:

  - `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

Whether the regex is more efficient or not, you need to test the solution in C#. To use the regex efficiently, declare as a `readonly` field using `RegexOptions.Compiled` and then call with `Regex.Match`. See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/w48SgQ):

```
private static readonly Regex rxFirst5Words = new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){4}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
// ...
var s = "The quick_brown, fox1 jumps over the lazy dog";
var result = rxFirst5Words.Match(s);
if (result.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use word boundaries (`\b`) to look for words instead of just `\w` and `\W`.

If I slightly modify your question to search the first N words and the N-1 'things between words' you might be able to use

```
Regex.Match("The quick_brown, fox1 jumps over the lazy dog", @"^(\b.+?\b){9}")
```

to get the expected result for N=5.

Note that this assumes that the input starts with a word.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a quick working code, I am posting the code I am using based on the accepted answer:

```
public static string GetFirstWordsRegEx(string s, int wordCount, string truncateSuffix = " [...]")
{
    // replace with string.Format for C# less than 6.0
    string pattern = $@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){{{wordCount - 1}}}";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var match = regex.Match(s);
    if (!match.Success)
        return s;

    var ret = match.Value;
    return ret.Length < s.Length ? ret + truncateSuffix : ret;
}
```

It gets the first `wordCount` words along with their separators or all the text, if it has less than `wordCount`. Also, allows to append a suffix when truncation takes place.

**[EDIT]**

`Wiktor Stribiżew`'s doubt about which solution has greater performance made test it. I will call first solution "classical", the second "Regex normal" and the third "Regex compiled".

The first one is within the question, the second one at the beginning of this answer and the third one below:

```
    // generated all possible text truncation patterns
    private static readonly List<Regex> FirstWordRegexes = new List<Regex>
    {
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){0}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){1}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){2}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){3}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){4}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){5}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){6}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        // ...
        // removed for brevity
        // ...
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){147}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){148}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+){149}", RegexOptions.Compiled),
    };

    public static string GetFirstWordsRegExOptimized(string s, int wordCount, string truncateSuffix = " [...]")
    {
        var regex = FirstWordRegexes[wordCount-1];
        var match = regex.Match(s);
        if (!match.Success)
            return s;

        var ret = match.Value;
        return ret.Length < s.Length ? ret + truncateSuffix : ret;
    }
```

**Test code**

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
var rand = new Random();
const int minValue = 20;
const int maxValue = 150;

#region warm up
sw.Start();
Console.WriteLine($"Warming up...");

// _testStrings contains 100K random real texts which may be longer or not than first words truncation value
foreach (var str in _testStrings)
{
    var dummy = str;
}
Console.WriteLine($"Warm up took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
#endregion

#region Classic C# approach
foreach (var str in _testStrings)
{
    int wordCount = rand.Next(minValue, maxValue);
    var firstWords = Utils.GetFirstWords(str, wordCount);
}
Console.WriteLine($"Classic code took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
sw.Restart();
#endregion

#region Uncompiled regex
sw.Start();
foreach (var str in _testStrings)
{
    int wordCount = rand.Next(minValue, maxValue);
    var firstWords = Utils.GetFirstWordsRegEx(str, wordCount);
}
Console.WriteLine($"Uncompiled regex code took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
sw.Restart();
#endregion

#region Compiled regex
sw.Start();
foreach (var str in _testStrings)
{

    int wordCount = rand.Next(minValue, maxValue);
    var firstWords = Utils.GetFirstWordsRegExOptimized(str, wordCount);
}
Console.WriteLine($"Compiled regex code took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
sw.Restart();
#endregion
```

**Results**

> Classic code took 953 ms
>
> Uncompiled regex code took 5559 ms
>
> Compiled regex code took 4194 ms

As expected, compiled regex was faster than uncompiled one. However, the classic version was much faster.

Comment: Note that you probably do not want to use RegexOptions.Compiled for a regular expression that you create on each invocation. Wiktor's answer explicitly moved that into a (static) field for that reason, to create/compile it once. Given that your expression changes with the input ('number of words') I'd probably keep your way (i.e. in the method), but remove that option completely. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7 and measure/decide for yourself

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have removed it. Thank you.